# Obtener datos de input type date con php

Tags: php, html, formularios

Alguien me puede ayudar a obtener datos de un input type date?;

```
<form id="Formulario" method="post"><br>
    <label style="display:block; overflow:hidden;">Fecha de nacimiento</label>
    <input type="date" id="fecha" name="Fecha"  min="2018-03-25" max="2018-05-25" step="2">
    <input type="submit" name="Insertar" class="" style="margin-left:20px; margin-top:20px;" value="Insertar Registro">
</form>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. ¿Qué has investigando/intentado para obtenerlo?  La etiquita `form` estaba mal cerrada.

Comment: Ya probaste <?=$_POST["Fecha"]?> :)

Comment: Pon qué estás haciendo en la parte de php para poder ayudarte

Answer (score 1):

el problema está en que no le dices a que archivo envias los datos, en resumen te falta el action:
Aquí está corregido.

```
<form class="" action="recibe.php" method="post">
    <label style="display:block; overflow:hidden;">Fecha de nacimiento</label>
    <input type="date" id="fecha" name="Fecha"  min="2018-03-25" max="2018-05-25" step="2">
    <input type="submit" name="Insertar" class="" style="margin-left:20px; margin-top:20px;" value="Insertar Registro">
</form>
```

Codigo Php para recibir la variable:

**$fecha= $_POST['Fecha'];**

**echo $fecha;**

Te aconsejo no poner mayuscula a los name, ya que te puede llevar confuciones.

pd:si no pones el action se  envian los valores por defecto al mismo archivo, pero para recibirlos tienes que crearlo en formato .php y no .html

suerte!